# How to set array of object empty in state object using useState in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to set array of object empty in state object using useState in React JS. I have below component on changing the drop down i need to set the object empty or remove from state object.

```
const FormComponent = () => {
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({});
  
onChange = (value, field) => {
let value = {...formValue, value};
setFormValue(value);
}

  return (
 <>
// Form component goes here with input , dropdown. And having common onChange Method for all element
</>
)

}
```

So, we have dropdown option like Admin, User Client. When Admin value selected from dropdown then below formValue object is coming

```
formValue = {
 admin: [{
text: "admin"
}],
content: "",
type: "Admin"
}
```

Now if i change the value from admin to "user" then form value showing as below

```
 formValue = {
     admin: [{
    text: "admin"
    }],
    user: [{
    text: "user"
    }],
    content: "",
    type: "User"
    }
```

How can i remove the admin object property/empty array object from the formValue Object whenever i change the dropwdown value from admin to user.

Only it should store respective property whenever drop down value have like Admin, User Client

Answer (score 0):

### Just change your `onChange` function to this

```
onChange = (value, field) => {
  setFormValue(value); 
}
```

The problem with the below statement that it is combining the `formValue` and the `value`

```
let value = {...formValue, value}; // **value**
```